# Dynamically parsing HTML with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I have hit a small problem. I would like to set different menus depending on the user being authenticated or not. Depending on the status laravel returns different menu structures (html).

**Here's my HTML for the main menu:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#start" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/image"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ng-bind-html="firstoption" ng-class="{active:isActive('/firstoption')}">{{ firstoption }}</li>
          <li ng-bind-html="secondoption" ng-class="{active:isActive('/secondoption')}" class="dropdown">
            {{ secondoption }}
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Heres my Controller:**
The backend returns a json with the html. The reason why I want to do it like that has also to do with user rights. Depending on different rights, different options are shown in the menu.

```
AppControllers.controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', '$location',  
  function ($scope, $http, $sce, $location) {

      $scope.isActive = function(route) {
        return route === $location.path();
      }

      $scope.firstoption = "";
      $scope.secondoption = "";

      var getMenuStructure = $http.get('/menustructure').success(function (data) {
        $scope.firstoption = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.firstoption);
        $scope.secondoption = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.secondoption);
      });

}]);
```

It seems to work nearly perfectly, but the console still gives me an error:

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'indexOf'

Is there a more elegant way of doing it? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
The problem seems to be the `$sce.trustAsHtml();`. When I remove it, the dropdowns don't work anymore and when I add them I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

The [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) allows you to include data from an external URL and compile it on the fly.

This will allow you to write code like this:

```
<ng-include src="/views/{{viewname}}.html"></ng-include>
```

and then in your controller,  simply set (or change) the view by setting `$scope.viewname`, like so:

```
$scope.viewname = "view"
```

Even if you don't need to dynamically change which page is loaded, it's worth using the ng-include for simplicities sake.

Comment: thx for the answer, but I don't really wanna include another html document, just bascially inject some html. Isn't there another way?

Comment: @Tino that logic makes no sense...you are already making an ajax call to get the html from backend, if you use `ng-include` instead angular will make the same call and html will be properly compiled during digest cycle

Comment: I come from a heavy jQuery background and need to get my head around the angular way... could you show me an example pls? I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. I found that $sce.getTrusted worked the same as trustAsHtml for my case. It looks like this: $sce.getTrusted($sce.HTML, someHtml)